# BigData analysis choose technology stack

Tags: hadoop, nosql, analysis, bigdata

I want to write an application that is able to generate reports and enable interactive data analysis (OLAP-like) from monitoring data from a large production system. (I know, there are some problematic trade-off decisions ahead, but let's keep them aside for now.)
I identified the following possibilities for the basic tech stack:

- Hadoop: for the distributed file system and MapReduce framework
- Database: HBase or Cassandra to enable random reads
- Analysis: Hive or Pig for advanced analysis

Based on my research I tend to believe that Hadoop/HBase/Hive would be the most common combination. But this is only based on a number of forum questions and product presentations.
Can someone else share his general opinion on the subject?
Or to be more specific answer the following questions:

- Is HBase in general a more suitable store for big data analysis than Cassandra (write vs. read performance)?
- Is it worth it to use a database or should I found my analysis layer directly on Hadoop?
- Which database/analysis tool combinations are the most "natural"?
- Did I miss any cool stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd be running HBase on the same cluster as Hadoop, you'd really cut down the memory available for MapReduce jobs. You don't really need random read/update capability of HBase for an OLAP system. You can load your data into Hadoop cluster using Flume or manually. The equipment monitoring data lends itself to partitioning by time, for example by calendar date. After you load your data into a directory structure that can be mapped to a partitioned Hive table, you can query it using HiveQL. For the most tricky analysis you can either write MapReduce jobs in Java or use Pig.

The problem is that responses would not come instantaniously. This is OK for ad-hock analysis, but might be frustrating if you trying to look at some commonly used pre-determined metrics. In the later case you should consider precalculating such metrics and loading results into a memory cache or even in a relational database. I have seen such frequently used results cached in HBase, I just cannot get over wasting half of the available RAM on a cluster for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I would upvote, if I had the rep). Since you seem to have experience in the area, did you ever use one of the "real-time" query frameworks (Cloudera Impala, Apache Drill, Spark/Shark)?

Comment: No, not really. I'd been out of this area for about a year now, so I might have missed some latest developments.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO,

1- Keeping all the recent advancements into consideration it's kinda difficult to decide on whether to use HBase or Cassandra based on just your read/write needs. You can tune these tools to fit into your read/write requirements. There are few more things which you should consider while making any decision.

2- You don't seem to have any need for a DB at this point. You can map your data, stored in HDFS, to Hive tables. Then run Hive queries whenever you need long running batch processes. And if you intend to perform real-time ad-hoc queries on some part of your data, you can use Cloudera Impala on the same Hive tables(when `real-timeness` is important). Impala uses same Hive metadata. So you don't have to worry about that.

3- If you are planning to work on Hadoop platform then HDFS+Hive+HBase+Pig would be good. I'm not saying Cassandra is bad, but Hbase was developed ground up to be used with Hadoop.

4- There are lot of 'cool' things out there, but you are better off keeping the number low. More tools means more configuration and more setup and more management(more headache). So start with only those things which are really required and add a particular tool only if you think it is really required or if it is going to give you some extra edge. But you might wanna have a look at tools like `Impala, Storm, Flume, Spark/shark` etc.

AFAIK, HBase was built to be used on top of a Hadoop cluster. No doubt it will eat some memory, but that should not be a bottleneck for your app. You just have to tune everything properly. But go for it and only if you need random real-time read/write access to your data.

Comment: +1 on using HBase only if you need random real-time read/write access to the data.